# ODataQueryOptions not being applied

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I may be missing something simple but based on this blog post: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options this should be working.  I have the following controller method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<DtoAgent> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Agent> options, bool includeInactive = false, bool includeDeleted = false)
    {
        IQueryable<Agent> agents = null;
        if (includeDeleted && includeInactive)
        {
            agents = agentRepository.FindAll();
        }
        else if (includeDeleted)
        {
            agents = agentRepository.FindBy(a => a.ussiStatus == "A");
        }
        else if (includeInactive)
        {
            agents = agentRepository.FindBy(a => !a.IsDeleted);
        }
        if (agents == null)
        {
            agents = agentRepository.FindByExp(a => a.ussiStatus == "A" && !a.IsDeleted);
        }
        options.ApplyTo(agents);
        return agents.ToDtos<DtoAgent>();
    }
```

when I call it like ../api/Agent?$top=10 it returns all results not just 10.  I can see the TopQueryOption in the options variable but it does not appear to get applied.  It works if I use the [Queryable] attribute but the top is applied after the DB call which is what I am trying to avoid.  I am calling EnableQuerySupport at the global level and have both the Nuget package and 2012.2 update installed.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing something simple. When you call ApplyTo, it doesn't mutate the IQueryable, it returns the applied query. So something like this should work instead:

```
var queryResults = options.ApplyTo(agents) as IQueryable<Agent>;
return queryResults.ToDtos<DtoAgent>();
```