# OdataQueryOptions generates null expression

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

When i run the following OData query against my controller method defined in below sample code, the resulting query in Get() becomes null:
http://my.host/api/MyClass/?$filter=Id eq 1&$expand=MySecondClass

The answer in [ODataQueryOptions not being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087427/odataqueryoptions-not-being-applied) suggests that this is the way to do it, but it still fails. Yes, MyClass do have a reference to MySecondClass. :)

EDIT: After a little more research, it seems query is null only when I'm using $expand. Using $filter, everthing works as expected. are there some traps with using $expand that I'm not aware of?

```
public MyClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MySecondClassId { get; set; }
    public MySecondClass MySecondClass { get; set; }
}

public MySecondClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public MyDbContext : DbContext {
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<MyClassDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<MyClass> options)
{
    var dbContext = new MyDbContext();
    IQueryable<MyClass> myClasses = dbContext.MyClasses;
    var query = options.ApplyTo(myClasses) as IQueryable<MyClass>; // query is null!
    query.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<MyClass, MyClassDto>).AsQueryable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use $expand or $select, and then use the ApplyTo method, the result is no longer an IQueryable, which is why you get back null. In this case, I see no reason why you would want to use the ApplyTo method other than to keep using AutoMapper. You would be better off ditching Automapper, projecting into your DTO, and decorating the method with [Queryable].